# Should I omit the "assign" qualifier when declaring primitive properties?

Tags: objective-c

My colleague objected in code review that declaring a CGFloat obj-c property with assign qualifier is superfluous as it is assign implicitly.
He says this is all I need.

```
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat cornerRadius;
```

However two other colleagues say that it helps to explicitly say assign to improve  readability and ensure that in case a fundamental changes happening in clang when  the default becomes something else, my explicit assign will be still there and I can sleep better knowing that.

Is this qualifier optional and its use a matter of personal preference?

Comment: Closing as primarily opinion-based.  However I would side with the people who say add `assign`.

Comment: What opinion? The answer to my question can be reasoned about logically. It's not a painting to have a subjective opinion. If there are two correct answers, it is also fine i didn't say it is not possible. Where exactly is there opinion and subjective taste?

Comment: Because it's an optional property for certain data types.  It's like asking "do I need to add `int` to `unsigned int` or not?".  Both are correct and down to personal preference or coding standards.  Hence opinion.

Comment: In the world of computing, it is almost always better to be unambiguous. So yeah, make it explicit, so there is no guessing/looking up the default value.

Comment: @trojanfoe See my update in last sentence.

Comment: @EarlGrey I updated my answer based on your updated question.

Answer (score 2):

They are both right. It's a style choice really. Default values are not required. But personally I put `assign` because it's clear and self-documenting. No need to remember what the default is.

In the end it is a personal choice or the choice of whatever coding standards you need to follow.

Update based on the updated question:

Yes, the use of `assign` in a property is optional and yes, it is a matter of personal preference whether you choose to use it or not.

Comment: So the question is off-topic?

Comment: I would also side with adding for the `Non need to remember what the default is`.